# FFmpeg audio capturing from mic is not working properly

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture

I am using the ffmpeg-20130205-git-c2dd5a1-win64-static version, I am trying to capture the audio and video and send it to the FMS server, I have tried with the following code initially

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Rear Input (SoundMAX Integrated Digital High Definition Audio)" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 600k -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/mystream
```

it through the following error

```
[dshow @ 00000000023f8920] Could not find audio device.
video=Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920:audio=SoundMAX Integrated Digital High Definit
ion Audio): Input/output error
```

Then I modified the code as follows its working fine

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Rear Input (SoundMAX Integrated" -b:v 600k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/mystream
```

I am unable to understand why its not accepting the full name of the audio driver and if I use the libx264 with the Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920  its not giving the video, video is blank (note: while using the iball c2.0 camera I am able to get the video)

what is the wrong in my code? how to publish in the libx264 format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Rear Input (SoundMAX Integrated" -b:v 600k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/mystream
```

after adding -pix_fmt yuv420p the problem is resolved